# EXTJS: How to save Form submit values without Database?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to save my form fields without DB and display this value in Grid.

I tried to output as JSON format. but its temporary. I want save as permanent value either in PHP or JSON structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save it to a text file on the server side. Just write server side processing to write data to a text file. I don't know why you would though. There are plenty of free open source SQL and non-sql databases out there that you can use. You could use couchdb or something similar to store your JSON data directly.

Comment: this is a different question. please mark this one as accepted and ask a different specific question showing some work and what you have so far.

Comment: Hi Dbrin, Duty assigned by boss to work local withoutDB. After filling values and submitted. Get that value and display in Grid. Thats it. As very very new to EXTJS, still looking for solution to get value from FORM and display in GRID.